# Advice on getting discounts in Paris for 15 year old (and 50 year old)

Tags: budget, france, paris, museums

My daughter and I are going to Paris for 6 days in late March I'm still trying to decide which museums/attractions to see although the followings are must sees:
1) Versaille
2) Louve
3) The Catacombs

Specific Questions:
Is it advisable to get a "museum pass". Where does one order one?  Are there discounts for 15 year olds?  How about 50 year olds?  My daughter does have a French passport (but is a resident of US) if that's of any help.  She speaks french somewhat fluently.  Any discounts for DisneyLand? How do I get advance tickets (discounts?) for the Catacombs?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: This is way too many questions for one post. Questions that are closely related are fine in one post but you're asking about museum passes, Disneyland, the Catacombs, things for 15-year-olds, accommodation _and_ travel. That should be at least six different questions. However, all your "*" questions are completely subjective so they're off-topic, here. That cuts it down to three (museum passes, discounts at Disneyland, advance tickets for the Catacombs).

Comment: (The problem with multiple questions in a post is that you end up with a bunch of answers, each covering some part of the question, and it's very hard for somebody who comes along in the future to find the answer to the one part of the question they're interested in.)

Comment: Thanks David. I've removed the extra questions at the end.  I believe the questions are now all closely related and the overriding theme is "Discounts!"

Comment: Thanks but this is still three separate questions. Somebody who's interested in Disneyland doesn't want to have to hunt through answers about the Louvre and the Catacombs. "Discounts" is, as you say, a theme: an area of discourse including a huge range of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your daughter is entitled, as an EU citizen under 26, to *free* entrance at Versailles and public museums in Paris. Depending on how many museums you intend to visit, you may want a [Museum Card](http://en.parismuseumpass.com/). My family (non-EU) love museums; for us these cards *always* pay for themselves, especially since the option to go back the next day lets us duck out of museums at hours they are too crowded. (Louvre: I'm thinking of you.) In many places you can also jump the queue, if any, with the Pass.

I don't know about EuroDisney, which had zero attraction to my sons. You might see if your daughter would rather skip. You can access the ticket prices [here](http://www.disneylandparis.com/en-us/).

Comment: I have read to get the museum pass at the first museum you go to. Make it a small museum which does not have queues. I got mine from a tourist information office, again a small one without much of a queue.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Lazarus! I'd never heard that citizens got free entrance to Versailles and public museums.  I would have thought it was just residents of the EU (or France).  I suppose I'll now have to figure out which museums are public (Louvre?) and which are private.  In any case, I'll need some sort of pass for myself, so I'll check out your links.

Comment: @Willeke Some museums (e.g., your Rijksmuseeum) have a special counter for pass sales, then walk right in.

Comment: @Dave The Louvre is a public museum; please see the linked website in the answer for the enormous list included in the pass.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I did check out the links.  It seems like everything we want to see is a public museum with the exception of the Catacombs.  So I guess I just need tickets for me.  I'm leaning towards "pay as I go" as I'm not sure I want to be obligated to hit multiple museums on consecutive days.  I will try and book the Catacombs ahead of time as I hear there are long lines.  Thank you!

Comment: BTW, I showed my daughter your initial response about your boys having "zero attraction" for Paris DisneyLand and she lost interest.  That's peer pressure for you! So, thanks, you saved me a bundle in money and lost time.

Comment: For more free stuff for your daughter, check out "Gratuité pour les moins de 26 ans et enseignants" on this list https://www.parisinfo.com/decouvrir-paris/guides-thematiques/paris-gratuit/musees-et-monuments-gratuits-a-paris/les-musees-et-monuments-gratuits-a-paris